# Design HTML Element Created With jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating `HTML` element using `Ajax` call from server-side. Now the thing is, the design of the web page is responsive. Somehow I am unable to align the dynamically generated elements to the page as expected. Say with below `Ajax` call, the elements are created:

```
var html = "";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "MethodName",
  data: id,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
     $.each(data, function() {
         $.each(this, function(k, v) {
             html += '<div class="wrapper"><div class="content">Dynamic data here</div></div>';
         });
     });

     $(".divs").append(html);
   }
});
```

In the front-end, I've something like this:

```
<style>
    .content {
        float: right;
     }
</style>

<h4 class="content">Data here</h4>

<div class="container">
   <div class="divs">
   </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see, the heading **h4** is aligned top right to the page and in the div section **(.divs)**, I am trying to bind the dynamic content. Provided the same class to align both the elements in the same position, top right of the web page. But in any way, the design gets broken for the div section. I can understand, it's under parent div section and appended. So this could be the reason, but is there any way I can adjust the alignment of both the elements in the same position with `CSS`?

**N.B**: Though I am not interested to use `jQuery` for the design part, but I welcome any suggestion with it as well. One more thing, there is a loop in the `Ajax` call and I am maintaining a logic here to get each data individually, so one data at a time. Just to clarify.

Comment: It's not really clear from your description what is wrong. Is the HTML not being updated correctly? Do you need additional CSS to align things properly? It would really help if you could provide a sample of the *rendered* HTML, after the AJAX call. (Also, note that your AJAX call fails to clear the `html` variable on subsequent calls.)

Comment: The content in the div section **.divs** isn't aligned to the top right actually as done for the heading **h4** @kmoser.

Comment: Can you share the complete styles? In the example you only target the `.content` element.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to break float of your `.content` object by adding `<div style="clear: both;"></div>` after it and add `float: right` to `.divs > .wrapper`

Comment: This section `<div style="clear: both;">` will be put before closing tag of `div`, something like this - `<div class="wrapper"><div class="content">Dynamic data here</div><div style="clear: both;"></div>` @vodkaJedi?

Comment: @user8512043 No, your `.content` object is `float: right`, so my idea is to break the "floating" with `<div style="clear: both;"></div>`.

Comment: See if you can provide a solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64290532/design-shattered-in-different-screens @vodkaJedi.