# Design Shattered in Different Screens

Tags: html, jquery, css, responsive-design

I designed a web page where few of the `HTML` elements aren't responsive. These elements are dynamically generated with `jQuery` and I believe, there should be a way I can make them to look responsive. `Media Queries` are an option but if it's possible to use `BootStrap` (Though I am using it but in few cases, unable to do the designs perfect) or custom `CSS` to force them to be responsive. Here is a scenario where `HTML` element is created on successful `Ajax` call:

```
//Dynamic checkboxes as Flag For Review
$('.cbFlag').each(function () {
    $(this).hide().after('<div class="class_checkbox"></div>');
});

$('.class_checkbox').on('click', function () {
    $(this).toggle lass('checked').prev().prop('checked', $(this).is('.checked'))
});
```

Somehow I tried to make it fixed but failed:

```
.class_checkbox {
    width: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -5%;
    margin-left: 82%;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/1GnSqmp/example.png);
}

.class_checkbox.checked {
    width: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    background: url(https://i.ibb.co/jWxbHF5/example-02.png);
 }
```

In the same way, the page with other elements are bit shattered like the number and details sharing screenshots below: In **Image 2**, two divs are created and tried to use float left/right positioning, but this doesn't make them aligned accordingly (These are screenshots of screen resolution - 1920 * 1080, but in few cases when the resolution is small, the designs are perfect. Again for mobile view, the number and flag are shattered)

**Current View**:

**Image 1**:
[image: Image 1]

**Image 2**:
[image: Image 2]

**Expected View**:

[image: Expected View 1]

[image: Expected View 2]

Answer (score 1):

I've checked website, and you've overwrited Bootstrap, that's a worse solution for this. You should keep original Bootstrap, then make changes in another CSS file or inline style.

On the other hand, you have given `margin-top: -4%` to `.headerSection1`. That makes the part of text invisible.

Your page is not responsive. It extends the page's 100% width. This is because of giving negative values to containers.

I strongly recommend you to use Bootstrap's `container-fluid`, `row` and `col`s.

On about your question: Your `1` and `10` are in different div's. You can put them in same `div` and position that.

Comment: Your suggestion was really brilliant, specifically with `container-fluid` and I really appreciate it @sundowatch. Though I am bit stuck with the flag sign and the question number with the oblique sign. If you can provide me an idea how I can handle them as those are generated on `Ajax` call and at the moment, not aligned perfectly on devices. Here 's the login details again - passdent.com; user: jessi@abc.com; pass: 1 - 6. Check the **Best of Three** from **Practice** menu.